# Detect when Browser Scrolls Below a Certain Point

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser, browser

I have a webpage filled with divs, and when the page reaches 300px from the bottom, it loads more divs.
I'm having trouble finding a detection that works everywhere.

I need some JavaScript (i.e. not JQuery) if statement to put into the body's onscroll function that will detect the browser scrolling below 300px from the bottom, which works with IE, FF, Chrome, Opera, Safari, Android browsers, iBrowsers, etc.

Comment: You will need to use javascript to do this.  Are you able to add javascript to the page?

Comment: @cale_b Lol, it was so obvious to me that I completely forgot to mention it anywhere :/

Answer (score 1):

You could use a library like

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-appear/

And bind to the last element you dynamically display in each batch, so that when it comes into view, the next batch is shown.

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant to but forgot to add that the solution can't use JQuery.

Comment: Why not download it and see how they do it.

Comment: You're going to want to put that in the main question then, nobody is going to notice that comment.

Comment: you can't use jquery or you can't use 3rd party libraries at all?

Comment: No third party libraries, but I can copy small functions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can use jQuery's "scrollTop" method on the document object or possibly the body tag.

i.e.

```
if ($(document).scrollTop() > whatever) {
 doWhatever();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the OP says he can't use a jQuery solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to know the position of the point, then checks the window `scrollTop`

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() > point) {
 //Carry On
}
```